# Batch move files to directory with csv

Tags: file, batch-file, csv, directory, move

I have a folder with files that i need to be moved over to the directory listed in the csv file.  All the files are in one folder but they need to go to different directories.

**Here is a section of the csv file:**

```
FileName    WinDir
file_9h28o3wfn1.pdf C:\destdir22\89\226
file-ror5d8s1oul9.pdf   C:\destdir22\85\919\920
file-xl2wu4nn7m79.ppt   C:\destdir22\858\1009\1010
file-3lyz75p7ahwc.pdf   C:\destdir22\865\924
file-atxpspd8nkx6.pdf   C:\destdir22\865\924
file-6vyfocncyjum.pdf   C:\destdir22\865\924
file-2byf7w5z7o4n.pdf   C:\destdir22\865\924
file-oouex7tmwg8w.pdf   C:\destdir22\865\924
file-qgwnqknpcifc.pdf   C:\destdir22\865\924
file-1rrue5fu5y9a.pdf   C:\destdir22\865\924
file-vvtvglal3mzw.pdf   C:\destdir22\865\924
file-d4nvxol7l33r.pdf   C:\destdir22\865\1016
file-5sb1rw7okt8m.pdf   C:\destdir22\865\1016
file-i9ekmrif8u2v.pdf   C:\destdir22\865\1016
file-6ef37r3v98b3.pdf   C:\destdir22\865\1016
file-ht6bkcr4ke4c.pdf   C:\destdir22\865\1016
file-1uvz2w22ln8s.pdf   C:\destdir22\865\1016
file-vbrsuqpksm8f.pdf   C:\destdir22\865\1016
file-8mlc5phu8r5x.pdf   C:\destdir22\865\1016
file-2mf9sq9gbz64.pdf   C:\destdir22\858\1009\1010
file-oqavxq4ol2h1.pdf   C:\destdir22\858\1009\1010
file-f8octlvkf3v7.pdf   C:\destdir22\858\1009\1020
file-llarikazxeco.pdf   C:\destdir22\865\1016
```

Comment: OK. What is your problem (unclear as it missing CDM/PS1 code you've tried already)? Suggestion: read output of `for /?` - I think contains all information you need to improve this question.

Answer (score 2):

The script below gets the directory with files, where script is, and copies files from it to paths from csv. This you can execute the script having other working directory (please remove "echo" when executing real run).

```
set "scriptdir=%~dp0"
for /F "tokens=1,2" %%a in (file.csv) do (
    if not exist "%%b" mkdir "%%b"
    echo move /Y "%scriptdir%%%a" "%%b\"

)
```

Comment: It almost works.  But for %%b it shows up in the command prompt as #N/A.  What does that mean?  I've never heard of a result like that from a csv and there was nothing on the web.

Comment: Ok. The script should work just fine.  The top results of my csv had the correct destinations but the ones on the bottom had some errors in the functions.  Thanks for the help.